# Edit M13checkbox in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need help with using this customizeable checkbox: https://github.com/Marxon13/M13Checkbox I have already linked m13checkbox.h and .m classes and wrote import in bridge-header file, but i don't know how to create checkbox on my tableview and manipulate it.

I need to place checkbox in every cell by my own UITableCell class.

UPD.

I have done with adding checkbox in cell, but now i need to control it in addiction by my data in UITableViewController. I need to set checkbox to checked/unchecked state depending on my dataArray. I also need to set label for every checkbox from dataArray